# Do PHP array keys need to we wrapped in quotes?

Tags: php, arrays, syntax

Which one below is correct?  First code has no quotes in the $_GET array and the second one does, I know you are supposed to have them when it is a string of text but in this case it is a variable, also what about if the key is a number?

no quotes

```
function arg_p($name, $default = null) {
  return (isset($_GET[$name])) ? $_GET[$name] : $default;
}
```

with quotes

```
function arg_p($name, $default = null) {
  return (isset($_GET['$name'])) ? $_GET['$name'] : $default;
}
```

Comment: Parenthesis is `()` and not `''`. The latter are single quotes or apostrophes.

Comment: When you say parentheses () are you referring to () or brackets []?

If I'm not completely confused, or you've edited the post, it appears that the only difference between your two cases are the single quotes around '$name'.

Comment: Gumbo's answer is right.  Also, I'd point out that in this case, the version without single-quotes is almost certainly an error.  it would always behave the same, regardless of the value of $name.

Comment: Also, not trying to confuse you, but `$_GET["$name"]` would actually work the same as the version without quotes most of the time, but it is not correct

Comment: @kip: why is it an error? The function is meant to return a $_GET request variable if it exists with a value of $name, else return the value in $default. The first function is correct.

Comment: @snicker: I think @Kip meant "the version *WITH* single quotes", because that disables interpolation, so '$name' will always evaluate to '$name', regardless of the value of the $name variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first one will use the value of `$name` as key while the second will use the literal string `'$name'` as key.

Comment: @jasondavis: I assume you meant the *unknown offset*/*unknown index* notice. That’s because you should test if that item exists before trying to read it. One way to do that is `isset`, another `array_key_exists`.

Answer (score 7):

With PHP, `$_GET["$name"]` and `$_GET[$name]` are identical, because PHP will evaluate variables inside double-quotes. This will return the key of whatever the variable `$name` stores.

However, `$_GET['$name']` will search for the key of `$name` itself, not whatever the variable `$name` contains.

If the key is a number, `$_GET[6]`, `$_GET['6']`, and `$_GET["6"]` are all syntactically equal.

Answer (score 2):

- if the key is a variable

  $array[$key];

you don't have to quote it.

- but if it a literal string you must (it is not a string if you don't wrap it in quotes)

  $array['myKey'];

and you will get an notice if you do it like this

```
$array[mykey];
```

Comment: you won't get an error for $array[mykey]. you will only get a PHP Notice. check out http://thephpcode.blogspot.com/2009/09/php-speed-up-quote-your-strings.html for more about this.

Comment: From `PHP 7.2` you will get PHP Warning.

Comment: `define('mykey','mykey');` done, no notices