# Should I use single quotes or not when accessing an array within an array?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do PHP array keys need to we wrapped in quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381300/do-php-array-keys-need-to-we-wrapped-in-quotes)
>   [Is it okay to use array[key] in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405482/is-it-okay-to-use-arraykey-in-php)

This is the code I am running and I am wondering whether I should quote the word message with single quotes like the second line of code in this post. Which is best practice?

```
$post = array('message' => $result[message]);
```

Or this?

```
$post = array('message' => $result['message']);
```

Comment: The second version won't result in notice. Which you probably have turned off if you are asking this, so please enable them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do use strings!

Your first example, `$post = array('message' => $result[message]);`, would not execute the same if "`message`" were defined as a constant.

Also, with syntax highlighting,

```
// this
$post = array('message' => $result['message']);
// or this
$post = array('message' => $result["message"]);
// is more readable than this
$post = array('message' => $result[message]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the quotes for readability.   When someone is reading your code, they might think that [message] is a variable, when in reality it's supposed to be a literal string: 'message'.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect usage if the `message` constant is undefined or is defined but does not contain the value `"message"`:

`$post = array('message' => $result[message]);`

Why?

Writing `message` (without $ sign) means you are accesing a PHP [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php). PHP's default behaviour is to issue a notice that the constant is undefined, then convert the undefined constant's name to a value.